# Unable to come to feasible solution due to huge solution space in scheduling

Tags: optaplanner

I am using OptaPlanner to solve scheduling problem.
There are many constraints, but the one I am having an issue with right at this moment is Minimum, Maximum working hours.

The solution space is huge.

Imagine trying to scheduling hundreds of people for anywhere a week to a month.
Each day has may variations of shifts (numbering in 100s if not 1000s).
This includes a possibility for a day off shift, which is one out of all variations.

The solution space is 
   |Employees| * |Day1Shifts| * |Day2Shifts| * ... * |DayNShifts|

The hard constraint of Min/Max working hours in scenario of part-time work (e.g. 16 to 24 is very difficult to satisfy given that probability of selecting an empty shift is so low on any given day.

Is there any way to guide OptaPlanner to make it reach feasible solution faster for this sort of problem.

I have implemented incremental score calculation and I am definitely in 3,4K calculations per second range for very large problems (500 people for 30 days)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: 500 people for 30 days isn't that big. I've dealt with much bigger cases for customers. The 3.5k per second is a bit on the low side, but not that bad (anything below 1k is bad). I'd investigate better move selectors, benchmark some different algo's, maybe nearby selection although probably not and if it's optaplanner 7, I'd use try Partittioned Search for the CH and maybe a bit of time for LS before running a non-partitioned LS.

Comment: I was wondering if there is a way to use PillarChangeMoveSelector with entity specific ValueRangeProvider.  Yes, my entities need specific Value Range Providers, but these will be shared among subsets of entities.

I guess I could have a solution-wide provider and implement SelectionFilter that would only make a move to a valid value, but it looses some of the model transparency, which I liked.